# Is there any way i can convert .glade files to executable?

Tags: linux, bash, user-interface, gtk, glade

i have been making a GUI for my Bash script using Glade.
Is there anyway i can convert the .glade file to a executable file for Linux?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: Ok, so i have tryed the option "save as GtkBuilder" and in the format .xml that some other website told me, that got me no where.
And then i have searched for "how to convert .glade to executing format linux" no help there eaither.

Comment: Here is an example of using a GtkBuilder UI file in C: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html

Comment: Ok, so i tryed it multiple times, it worded, BUT i want to make my .glade file into an executing file, how would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't.**

Glade (or GtkBuilder) are just descriptions of the UI, which gets parsed by a (in C with Gtk3) `GtkBuilder` object which in turn creates your widgets according UI xml description **at runtime**. It does not generate *any* (with the exception for some callback/model-view connections) application logic.

Comment: So i can't do anything with the glade file to make the GUI runnable?

Comment: How do you imagine this should work, how should the button know what effect it should have on the rest of the UI? Write a python, C, ruby or whatever program. It's not that hard. Just take a few hours, sit on your but and read tutorials.

Comment: I have tryed python before, i never realy got any sucsess with it, i have however tryed C#, it was better to understand but i got comfused after a little while. Ruby i have heard about, i will take some study on it and see how it goes.

Comment: Don't chicken out - and ruby (afaik) is not in a good shape at all. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Yea, i have just resently started with python, havent been online at this website on a while, currently i LOVE python

Answer (score 0):

@drahnr has the correct answer: the way to make a glade file "runnable" is to write code that uses it. I'll just mention [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/unstable/) in case that's good enough for your use case -- it allows creation of simple dialogs and can be a fast way to create very simple UIs for scripts:

```
entry=$(zenity --entry \
               --title="Info needed" \
               --text="Enter a value:" \
               --entry-text "Default value")
echo "return value was $?";
echo "entered value was $entry";
```

Note that the possibilities are very limited compared to what you can do with actual code.

Comment: I have tryed zenity before, it can't have multiple dialogs in one window, drahnr is right, i will give ruby a shoot.